# Rewriting HTML tags with DOM/Xpath (PHP)

Tags: php, xpath

I'm parsing a block of HTML with DOM/Xpath in PHP. Within this HTML, there are a few `p` tags that I want to convert to `h4` tags, instead.

Raw HTML =>

```
<p class="archive">Awesome line of text</p>
```

Desired HTML =>

```
<h4>Awesome line of text</h4>
```

How can I do this with Xpath? I think I need to call on `appendChild`, but I'm not sure. Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Is the "block of HTML" valid XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it:

```
<?php
$html = <<<END
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p class="archive">Awesome line of text</p>
        <p>bye</p>
        <p class="archive">Another line of <b>text</b></p>
        <p>welcome</p>
        <p class="archive">Another <u>line</u> of <b>text</b></p>
    </body>
</html>
END;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Find the nodes we want to change
$nodes = $xpath->query("//p[@class = 'archive']");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // Create a new H4 node
    $h4 = $doc->createElement('h4');

    // Move the children of the current node to the new one
    while ($node->hasChildNodes())
        $h4->appendChild($node->firstChild);

    // Replace the current node with the new
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($h4, $node);
}

echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```